# Find probability given mutual independence (of 3 events)

Tags: probability, statistics, independence

A bus operator runs two bus routes from station 
to station 
. The first route is a direct bus, bus 
. The second route involves changing buses at an intermediate station: passengers take bus 
from station 
to station 
and then bus 
from station 
to station 
. The events of the three buses running are mutually independent and each bus runs with probability 1/3
. Which of the following gives the probability that a person can travel from station 
to station 
?

My working out
$P(AuBuC)=(1/3)+ (1/3)+ (1/3)-(1/3(1/3)-(1/3)(1/3)-(1/3)(1/3)+(1/3)(1/3)(1/3)$

Which gives me 19/27 , however this is incorrect, any hints to help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually need to calculate $$P( A \cup (B \cap C)) = P(A) + P(B\cap C) -P(A\cap (B\cap C)) $$ as to go from $X$ to $Y$, you either need bus $A$ to run, *or* both buses $B$ and $C$ to run.